# HP Fortify - Scanning in Release vs. Debug

Tags: .net, security, fortify

What differences occur if I scan a project with HP Fortify(16.11) in Release mode vs. Debug mode in .Net 4.5 or greater? I get a warning that if I continue (The HP Fortify Scan) in Release configuration the Scan procedure my produce incorrect results.